# angular ng-grid selected Items is blank after first iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, selecteditem

I am working on a bulk action on an ng-grid.  When selected all rows the selected items is correct the first time, but after the first bulk action, the selected items is blank. With the code below it sends a notification that "Must select at least 1 row to move."  Please let me know if you need any more details.  Thanks in advance.

```
vm.init = function() {
    vm.title = "Orphan Entries";
    selectReport("OrphanEntries");
};
/* initialization */
vm.init();

vm.gridOptionsReports = {
            data: 'vm.data',
            multiSelect: true,
            enableColumnResize: true,
            showFooter: true,
            showSelectionCheckbox: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
            selectedItems: [],
            selectionCheckboxColumnWidth: 25,
            enablePaging: true,
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions
        } 

$scope.applyBulkAction = function(){
    if(vm.selectedAction == 'notset'){
       Notification.error("You need to select a bulk action.");
    }else{
        var rows = vm.gridOptionsReports.selectedItems;
        if(rows.length < 1){
            Notification.error("Must select at least 1 row to move.");
        }else{
           var toggleTo = 0;
           if(vm.selectedAction == 'move'){
                toggleTo = 1;
            }
            var data = "";
            var first =true;
            for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++){
                if(rows[i].selectedToBeMoved != toggleTo){
                    if(first){
                        data = '{"ID":"'+rows[i].iD+'"}';
                        first = false;
                    }else{
                        data = data + ',{"ID":"'+rows[i].iD+'"}'
                    }
                }
            }
            if(data == ""){
               Notification.error("The rows that you have selected have already been flagged.")
                }else{
                    return ReportService.flagOrphansToBeMoved(data).then(flagOrphansToBeMovedComplete).catch(flagOrphansToBeMovedFailed);

                    function flagOrphansToBeMovedComplete(response) {
                        if(!response.data.error && response.data.status == 200){
                            Notification.success('Bulk action was successful.  All flagged rows will be moved during the next scan.');
                            //vm.gridOptionsReports.selectedItems = [];
                            vm.init();
                        }else{
                            Notification.error('Error scheduling to move orphan.');
                        }
                        return response;
                    }

                    function flagOrphansToBeMovedFailed(error) {
                        Notification.error('Error scheduling to move orphan.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UI

[image]

UI code:

```
<div class="row smallPaddingBot">
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <select ng-model="vm.selectedAction" class="form-control">
        <option value="notset">Bulk Actions</option>
        <option value="move">Flag Selected To Be Moved</option>
        <option value="dontMove">Flag Selected Not To Moved</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="applyBulkAction()">Apply</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting view as well?

Comment: @LeonardoLana I just added what it looks like as i step through each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was re-creating the ng-grid every time so I was getting lost in scope.  The solution was to set the gridOptionsReports.selectedItems to a scope variable and then reference that scope variable.

From:

```
selectedItems: [],
```

To:

```
selectedItems: vm.selectedRow,
```

And:

```
var rows = vm.gridOptionsReports.selectedItems;
```

To:

```
var rows = vm.selectedRows;
```